# Joomla 2.5 form field best practice for dynamic drop down list

Tags: joomla2.5

I need a drop down list that displays the next 10 years starting with the current. I have added the form field in my .xml file this way:

```
        <field 
        name="ccYear" type="sql" default="" label="Year"
        query="SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 as rownum, YEAR(CURDATE())+@rownum value FROM #__content, (SELECT @rownum:= -1) AS a limit 10" 
        key_field="value" 
        value_field="value" 
    />
```

This works well enough, but I feel like there might be a better way. The integer field type seems like a great candidate, but I don't know how to get the dynamic current year:

```
        <field name="ccYear2" type="integer" label="" class="ddDate" description="" first="2013" last="2023" step="1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own type field, just need to create class for it,
and put it into:
com_componen/models/fields/ccyear.php

```
jimport('joomla.form.formfield');

class JFormFieldCcyear extends JFormField
{
    protected $type = 'ccyear';

    protected function getInput()
    {
        $options = JHTML::_('select.integerlist', date('Y'), date('Y', strtotime("+10 years")), 1, 'year', 'class="inputbox"'); 

        return $options;
    }
}
```

How to use:

```
<field name="ccyear" type="ccyear" label="Year"/>
```